# ¿como extrapolar variable en el modo comando en vim?

Tags: vim

quiero saber como extrapolar las variables de vim , por ejemplo dar formato al fichero en el cual estoy trabajando.

```
:!fmt -w  mifichero
```

al estar trabajando en varios directorios el referenciar la ruta del fichero
resulta tedioso.

```
:!fmt -w /home/user/miproyect/lalaala/otro_directorio/otro_mas/mi_fichero
```

la idea seria extrapolar alguna variable de vim en el modo comando.

¿Alguien sabe?

Comment: Que quieres decir con extrapolar una variable?

Comment: No se si esta bien el termino, pero recuerdo que una vez leyendo esta acción la definían así.  Por ejemplo en python

`variable = "Jose"`

`print("%s amigo" %variable)`

los caracteres "%s" extrapolan la "variable" en la función.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En la línea de comandos puedes usar el comodín `%:p` para obtener el path completo del archivo que estás editando. Obviamente no te funcionará con un buffer que no hayas salvado aún al archivo, y claro, el comando solo actuará con los últimos cambios que hayas salvado. Por ejemplo:

```
:!fmt -w 80 %:p
```

Si quieres redirigir la salida al mismo buffer, puedes hacer

```
:r !fmt -w 80 %:p  # En la posicion actual
:0r !fmt -w 80 %:p # Al comienzo del buffer
```

O si quieres reemplazar el contenido completo:

```
:% !fmt -w 80 %:p
```